# Azure staging web deploy fails with ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_CREATEAPP but not for production

Tags: azure, command-line, webdeploy

I'm trying automated web site deployment in Azure and I'm at the phase were I run web deploy commands. The command for production works fine and updates the content but the one for staging is failing with the error code in the title.

I'm no sure were the problem is and if it is an authorization one I'm not sure where to set more permissions for the staging account.

This is the production command (which works):

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:package="MyTestingSite.zip" -dest:auto,ComputerName="https://mytestingsite.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=MyTestingSite",UserName="$mytestingsite",Password="fromProductionPublishProfile",authtype="Basic" -verb:sync
```

And this is the one for staging (which fails with ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_CREATEAPP)

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:package="MyTestingSite.zip" -dest:auto,ComputerName="https://mytestingsite-staging.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=MyTestingSite__staging",UserName="$MyTestingSite__staging",Password="fromStagingPublishProfile",authtype="Basic" -verb:sync -verbose
```

Help is greatly appreciated! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

Azure expecting that site name will be presented twice - in scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=%SiteNameHere%" and the same value as a parameter, by default value from file SetParameters.xml is used for second.

You may modify this file or pass parameter to msdeploy directly:

-setParam:name="IIS Web Application Name",value="%SiteNameHere%"

Comment: Thanks, this is not documented anywhere.

Comment: this worked! thanks for the answer! Unbelievable that it still not documented #teamcity

Comment: just needed to remove '%' from %SiteNameHere tks

Comment: After hours of troubleshooting, finally, this is the only solution that worked! Yes, it is indeed sad that this isn't clearly documented anywhere.

Comment: Silly question, but when deploying to an Azure Web App, what do you use for the site name ?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find where the problem was ...

In a settings file created by msdeploy.exe I was using the wrong site name. 
Sadly the documentation was popping up an error that had nothing to do with the wrong site name but only saying that it can't create that site because of the rights. Which somehow, in a twisted Microsoft like way, makes sense.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Hey @mosu, did you able to publish succesfully ? I'm still seeing the issue, Could you please help me

Comment: @rajanks To be honest, I don't remember. But according to my own comment above, it looks like I did. Check that the website name is correct, this was my problem. And also check Danila's comment.

Comment: How did you manage to chane the variable in the generated setting file? By a script or by passing another parameter to the build task? Thx!

Comment: @spikey: I'm sorry but I don't remember and I don't maintain the project anymore.

Comment: @mosu: no worries, thanks. I got it. In the Azure Release Pipeline I went to the Deplyoment process, selected `Deploy Azure App Service`, opened the `Additional Deployment Options` and set the parameter `SetParameters file` to point to my file `parameters.xml` containing the `{project name}_IisWebApplication_IIS` parameter. In the log this will cause an additional parameter `-setParamFile:{some temporary xml file}` to appear which actually contains (probably, because it works) the `parameter.xml` content.